# I am trying to deploy a VM with diagnosting settings

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, iaas

During the ARM template deployment, I get this error related to pre-existing Event Hub Name space - Sec-2-eventhub:

*The deployment 'Deployment-rg-vms-20220208010117' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource.
| Parent resource 'Sec-2-eventhub' not found. (Code:ParentResourceNotFound)*

This is my azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualMachineName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": " Virtual Machine Name"
      }
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Machine Size"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_B1ls",
        "Standard_DS1",
        "Standard_DS2",
        "Standard_DS3",
        "Standard_DS4"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Standard_B1ls"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Machine Administrator User Name"
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Machine Administrator Password"
      }
    },
    "eventHubNameSpace": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Existing Event Hub"
      }      
    },
    "diagStorageAccount": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Existing Storage Account Name"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkRG":  {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual Network Resource Group Name"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Existing Virtual Network Name"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Existing Subnet name"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "eventHubHubName": "logs",
    "eventHubPolicyName": "SendKey",
    "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS",
    "vnetID": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('virtualNetworkRG'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "publicIpAddressName": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-pip')]",
    "networkInterfaceName": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '-nic')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
      ],
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
          "windowsConfiguration": {
            "provisionVmAgent": true
          }
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "2019-Datacenter",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
            }
          },
          "dataDisks": [
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', variables('publicIpAddressName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIpAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().Name,'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', variables('publicIpAddressName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('publicIpAddressName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIpAllocationMethod": "dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '/IaaSDiagnostics')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
        "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5",
        "settings": {
          "WadCfg": {
            "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
              "overallQuotaInMB": 4096,
              "DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs": {
                "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Error"
              },
              "Directories": {
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "IISLogs": {
                  "containerName": "wad-iis-logfiles"
                },
                "FailedRequestLogs": {
                  "containerName": "wad-failedrequestlogs"
                }
              },
              "PerformanceCounters": {
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "sinks": "EventHub",
                "PerformanceCounterConfiguration": [
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Available Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT15S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\% Committed Bytes In Use",
                    "sampleRate": "PT15S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Committed Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT15S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor(_total)\\% Processor Time",
                    "sampleRate": "PT15S"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "WindowsEventLog": {
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "sinks": "EventHub",
                "DataSource": [
                  {
                    "name": "Application!Error"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Security!*"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "System!Critical"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Logs": {
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Error"
              }
            },
            "SinksConfig": {
              "Sink": [
                {
                  "name": "EventHub",
                  "EventHub": {
                    "Url": "[concat('https://', parameters('eventHubNameSpace'), '.servicebus.windows.net/', variables('eventHubHubName'))]",
                    "SharedAccessKeyName": "[variables('eventHubPolicyName')]"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "StorageAccount": "[parameters('diagStorageAccount')]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('diagStorageAccount')]",
            "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('diagStorageAccount')), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value]",
            "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net",
            "EventHub": {
              "Url": "[concat('https://', parameters('eventHubNameSpace'), '.servicebus.windows.net/', variables('eventHubHubName'))]",
              "SharedAccessKeyName": "[variables('eventHubPolicyName')]",
              "SharedAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualMachineName": {
      "value": "winvm"
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
      "value": "Standard_B1ls"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "myadmuser"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "value": "SomeS3curePassword!"
    },
    "eventHubNameSpace": {
      "value": "Sec-2-eventhub"      
    },
    "diagStorageAccount": {
      "value": "sec2ehdiag01"
    },
    "virtualNetworkRG":  {
      "value": "vnets-rg"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "value": "core-net"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my azuredepy.paramenters.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualMachineName": {
      "value": "winvm"
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
      "value": "Standard_B1ls"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "myadmuser"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "value": "SomeS3curePassword!"
    },
    "eventHubNameSpace": {
      "value": "Sec-2-eventhub"      
    },
    "diagStorageAccount": {
      "value": "sec2ehdiag01"
    },
    "virtualNetworkRG":  {
      "value": "vnets-rg"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "value": "core-net"
    }
  }
}
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: Your event hub Sec-2-eventhub does not exist.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. It did exist in its own RG.
It looks like it is looking for it in the same RG where VM is created. Deleted it and recreated it in the same RG now I get another error: "New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 4:29:57 PM - The deployment 'azuredeploy' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message:  (Code:NotFound)
CorrelationId: 922838b4-2caa-446c-aa44-662824feaedf"

Digging further I found this. 
Sec-2-eventhub/SendKey
Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/AuthorizationRules
NotFound

""